# Convert a Date in Xcode to timestamp before adding to firestore

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui, timestamp

I have a  `@State var tripDate = Date()`

I want to add to firestore db

```
  func addData(tripDate: Date) {
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        // Add a document to a collection
        db.collection("tripDate":tripDate]) { error in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil {
                // No errors
                
                // Call get data to retrieve latest data
                self.getData()
            }
            else {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
```

and also get data from firestore

```
func getData() {
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        // Read the documents at a specific path
        db.collection("Event").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil {
                // No errors
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                    // Update the list property in the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        // Get all the documents and create Todos
                        self.list = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            
                            // Create a Todo item for each document returned
                            return Event(id: d.documentID,
                                            tripDate: d["tripDate"] as! Date,
            
                                            
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            else {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the button to add

```
     Button(action: {
     Eventmodel.addData(tripDate: tripDate)
     }) {
     Text("Submit")
}
```

any idea how can I covert the date in these cases to timestamp (in these functions)  since Firestore doesn't take Date it rather takes timestamps and incase I remain putting it as a date, fatal error occurs and the app crashed and freezes , any idea thank you alot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Swift Firebase library has a class `Timestamp` with an initializer that takes a `Date`:

```
convenience init(date: Date)
```

And has a function that will convert a `Timestamp` to a `Date`:

```
func dateValue() -> Date
```

You could also calculate seconds and nanoseconds from a Date manually. That might look something like this:

```
extension Date {
    var secondsAndNanoseconds: (seconds: Int, nanoseconds: Int) {
      let result = timeIntervalSince1970
      let seconds = Int(result)
      return (seconds, Int(1000000000 * (result-Double(seconds))))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Date` into a timestamp by using its [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779963-timeintervalsince1970) property. If the API you're using supports floating point numbers, you can use it as is, or just convert it to a `String`. An alternative could be using a [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).